# How long before spark plugs show use?

Tags: sparkplugs

I have some spark plugs here from a Toyota Yaris that theoretically have only been driven with a handful of times essentially about a week old, but I suspect that these might be a little over 2 years old minimal usage. It's important to point out that I was experiencing multiple cylinder misfire with 3 bad coils and a full open fuel injector. Anyone have an opinion or any information on this subject of identifying the age of a spark plug?[image] The top of one of the less messy plugs [image]

Answer (score 1):

[Iridium spark plugs](https://www.championautoparts.com/Parts-Matter/automotive-repair-and-maintenance/Spark-Plug-Materials.html) should go *a very, very long time* before showing much wear and tear.  Given the modest cost of them, there's no reason not to use them.

However, that depends on the fuel injection system and spark system working as the factory intended (which in turn is required to have the smog systems work as intended).  If the car is having trouble, that will create a great deal of soot and gunk and contaminate the plugs quickly.  That is not the plugs' fault.

I would think a car with problems like that would be borderline undriveable, but should also produce lots of useful PTC codes to help diagnose the trouble.

Fix all spark and fuel injection issues and see if the plugs perform then.

Also if it's a flood car, forget it. They're pretty much unrepairable.